# Maven: how to create a repo-style structure from deps without transitive dependencies

Tags: maven

I'm using the maven-assembly-plugin to create a Maven Repo-style directory structure of my project dependencies with the following descriptor:

```
<assembly>
  <id>my-repo</id>
  <formats>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <includeMetadata>false</includeMetadata>
      <outputDirectory>my-output-repo</outputDirectory>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</assembly>
```

However, I'm finding that the produced repo also contains transitive dependencies and I want my top-level dependencies only. I have already excluded transitive dependencies on the pom level and they don't show up when I do `mvn dependency:tree`, however I keep seeing them in my generated repo.

I can individually suppress them with `<exclude>` elements in the assembly descriptor, but this is error-prone because you might never know whether another transitive dep might be pulled in.

Other output modes in the assembly plugin have a `<useTransitiveDependencies>` tag and the `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies` also has such a setting, however they don't produce a repo-style structure.

Is there a way in which I can produce a repo-style structure from my direct deps without also pulling in the transitive ones?

Edit: Tome's comment below provides a solution to this.

Comment: What is the scope of your dependencies on your POM file?

Comment: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies does have a _<useRepositoryLayout>_ option. And using the assembly plugin, you might use _<outputFileNameMapping>_ to control the structure of your _dependencySet_.

Comment: @Tome that solves it! I didn't spot that option with the maven-dependency-plugin, but it does exactly what I'm looking for , thanks! (@Jorge the scope was 'compile')